# Polyharmonic spline implementation c#

Tags: c#, algorithm, interpolation

I search a implementation of "Polyharmonic spline" in c#. I only found this library [Altaxo](https://github.com/Altaxo/Altaxo). I search a library where   available through nuget and licence is apache or mit.

My use case is find the average temperature of definied points on a 2d map. For example on

- position1 (x:0 y:0 temperature: 10°)
- position2 (x:0 y:30 temperature: 100°)
- position3 (x:40 y:0 temperature: 50°)
- position4 (x:30 y:30 temperature: 20°)

the red points are the calculated values.

[image: Temperature map]

**Code Example**

```
using Altaxo.Calc.Interpolation;
using Altaxo.Calc.LinearAlgebra;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Spline
{
    private PolyharmonicSpline _spline;

    public Spline()
    {
        var items = new List<TemperaturePosition>()
        {
            new TemperaturePosition(0,0,10),
            new TemperaturePosition(0,30,100),
            new TemperaturePosition(40,0,50),
            new TemperaturePosition(30,30,20),
        };

        var xCoordinates = items.Select(o => o.X).ToArray();
        var yCoordinates = items.Select(o => o.Y).ToArray();
        var values = items.Select(o => o.Temperature).ToArray();

        this._spline = new PolyharmonicSpline();
        this._spline.Construct(new DoubleVector(xCoordinates), new DoubleVector(yCoordinates), new DoubleVector(values));
    }

    public double Calculate(double x, double y)
    {
        return this._spline.GetInterpolatedValue(x, y);
    }
}

public class TemperaturePosition
{
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
    public double Temperature { get; set; }

    public TemperaturePosition(double x, double y, double temperature)
    {
        this.X = x;
        this.Y = y;
        this.Temperature = temperature;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It actually isn't that hard to implement a similar interpolation yourself using barycentric interpolation instead of splines. Here's a [practical guide to barycentric interpolation](https://classes.soe.ucsc.edu/cmps160/Fall10/resources/barycentricInterpolation.pdf) that might help.

For some code, have a look at this [answer on gamedev.stackexchange.com](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/23745/55886):

```
// Compute barycentric coordinates (u, v, w) for
// point p with respect to triangle (a, b, c)
void Barycentric(Point p, Point a, Point b, Point c, float &u, float &v, float &w)
{
    Vector v0 = b - a, v1 = c - a, v2 = p - a;
    float d00 = Dot(v0, v0);
    float d01 = Dot(v0, v1);
    float d11 = Dot(v1, v1);
    float d20 = Dot(v2, v0);
    float d21 = Dot(v2, v1);
    float denom = d00 * d11 - d01 * d01;
    v = (d11 * d20 - d01 * d21) / denom;
    w = (d00 * d21 - d01 * d20) / denom;
    u = 1.0f - v - w;
}
```

Having this, you just need to triangulate your given values - e.g. in your example, use one triangle for the data points 10, 50, 100 and another triangle for the data points 20, 50, 100.

Splines are used for "smoother" interpolation that ensures curvature continuity.

Answer (score 0):

@schnaader I have converted your barycentric example to C#.
The proposal does not solve my problem, now i need an additional logic to calculate the temperature. And it is not easy work with more as 3 points.

C# Example ([Install-Package System.Numerics.Vectors](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Numerics.Vectors))

```
Tuple<float, float, float> Barycentric(Vector2 p, Vector2 a, Vector2 b, Vector2 c)
{
    Vector2 v0 = b - a, v1 = c - a, v2 = p - a;
    float d00 = Vector2.Dot(v0, v0);
    float d01 = Vector2.Dot(v0, v1);
    float d11 = Vector2.Dot(v1, v1);
    float d20 = Vector2.Dot(v2, v0);
    float d21 = Vector2.Dot(v2, v1);

    float denom = d00 * d11 - d01 * d01;
    var v = (d11 * d20 - d01 * d21) / denom;
    var w = (d00 * d21 - d01 * d20) / denom;
    var u = 1.0f - v - w;
    return new Tuple<float, float, float>(v, w, u);
}
```